# Finding the value of an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Here is an expression that can be easily shown to equate 2 by analysis.
$$\sqrt[3]{7+\sqrt{50}}+\sqrt[3]{7-\sqrt{50}}$$
But no matter what i try Mathematica always shows a complex result:2.62132 + 0.358719 i

And Solve function returns error when i attempt to solve over reals.

How can i make this to evaluate to 2?

Comment: Look in the documentation for Surd

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Thank you, this command was new to me :-)

Comment: @Aman Nice little problem. I deplore the closing.

Answer (score 4):

Another way

```
CubeRoot[7 + Sqrt[50]] + CubeRoot[7 - Sqrt[50]] // FullSimplify
(*2*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Surd[7 + Surd[50, 2], 3] + Surd[7 - Surd[50, 2], 3] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Also, `Surd[7 + Surd[50, 2], 3] + Surd[7 - Surd[50, 2], 3] // RootReduce`

Answer (score 3):

Observing that $7- \sqrt {50}\lt 0$ and letting `(-1)^(1/3)->-1` we have

```
FullSimplify[(7 + Sqrt[50])^(1/3) - (-7+ Sqrt[50])^(1/3)]

(* Out 2 *)
```

Thanks to @yarchik.

Comment: Maybe it is good to say that $7-\sqrt{50}<0$.